# Cannot find DAG on airflow dags list

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver, airflow-taskflow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCHHL.png)
It's the first time I tried to create airflow dag but when I checked the dag lists in terminal, there is no dag_id that I created

Is there anything wrong with my file or the directory of the dag the I created

Comment: what is your AIRFLOW_HOME ? is it set correctly ? try to run airflow dags list -S dags_folder and check if you see it

Comment: @ozs I tried to run airflow das list -S airflow/dags, it showed the same result (only example dag)

Comment: cd ${AIRFLOW_HOME} is /home/rattapong

Comment: try to put in full path of your code dags folder. i can't tell if its the same from the print screen. also, in the web-ui do you see this dag ? is it enabled ?